# How to embed a file and then save it to a location?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, embedded-resource, memorystream

I've added a `test.zip` to a C# project by creating a `Resource1.resx` and dragged to the resx tab. It is now visible in the Solution Explorer as a child of `Resources`.

When the program runs, I'd like to move it from the .exe to a location on the computer like My Documents.

I've a feeling I need to convert the resource to a memory stream before I can write it to file but I'm not sure how to access the file as resource or how to convert it.

I *think* the following extracts the resource object (then again, it doesn't error no matter what the first param is) but I'm not sure how to proceed:

```
var resource = new ResourceManager("test", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you activate the resources you have already a `ResourceManager`.Just use `GetObject` method,get the bytes of your file and write the them to a new file with `File.WriteAllBytes`:

```
var bytes =  Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("resourceName") as byte[];
File.WriteAllBytes("newFile.zip", bytes);
```

Comment: I would say `GetObject` is better but it's your choice, use whichever you like

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`.

```
using (Stream x = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("test"))
{
    ...
}
```

Reference to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).